# custom arrayadapter notifyDataSetChanged causes crash

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have a custom `ArrayAdapter` PlayerAdapter that refers to an `ArrayList` of Players. I'm trying to add new Players to the `ArrayList` then update the `ListView` via `notifyDataSetChanged`, but it is causing a crash. I think I need to provide some additional overrides to my custom PlayerAdapter, but I don't know what needs to be fixed. I've searched other topics [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example) but everything has been slightly different. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious...

Crash log

```
03-04 09:43:50.836 3016-3016/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.laudev.android.crossoff, PID: 3016
                                             java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4
                                                 at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                 at com.laudev.android.crossoff.PlayerAdapter.getView(PlayerAdapter.java:53)
                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
                                                 at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
                                                 at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
                                                 at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1356)
                                                 at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1651)
                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

PlayerAdapter.java

```
public class PlayerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Player> {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<Player> data;

public PlayerAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Player> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = new ArrayList<Player>(data);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    PlayerHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new PlayerHolder();
        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        holder.txtName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        holder.txtScore = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtScore);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (PlayerHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Player player = data.get(position);
    holder.txtName.setText(player.name);
    holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(player.icon);
    holder.txtScore.setText("" + player.score);

    return row;
    }

static class PlayerHolder
    {
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtScore;
    }
}
```

Player.java

```
public class Player {
public int icon;
public String name;
public int score;
public Player(){
    super();
    }

public Player(int icon, String name, int score) {
    super();
    this.icon = icon;
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
    }
}
```

And lastly the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private PlayerAdapter adapter;
private ListView listViewPlayers;
private List<Player> player_data;

// Called when activity is first created
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initialize view with 4 players
    player_data = new ArrayList<Player>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        player_data.add(new Player(R.drawable.red, "Player " + i, 0));
    }

    // Set adapter with the four players above
    adapter = new PlayerAdapter(this,
            R.layout.simplerow, (ArrayList<Player>) player_data);

    // Hook up ListView with adapter
    listViewPlayers = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.playerList);
    listViewPlayers.setAdapter(adapter);
}

// press button to add a new player to ListView
public void addPlayer (View v) {
    int nextPlayerNum = player_data.size() + 1;
    player_data.add(new Player(R.drawable.blue, "Player " + nextPlayerNum, 0));
    // EDIT: commenting out this line since not necessary. Still seeing crash. 
    // adapter.add(new Player(R.drawable.blue, "Player " + nextPlayerNum, 0));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

Comment: Can you post the crash log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like answering your own question is frowned upon here...but I'll do it anyway. The problem was in the constructor for `PlayerAdapter.java`. The line

```
this.data = new ArrayList<Player>(data);
```

should be replaced with

```
this.data = data;
```

so that the new ArrayAdapter and the global list in `MainActivity.java` are referring to the same object. Thanks to everyone for helping me get here...I used the debugger and found that there was an out of bounds exception, then found that there were two different `ArrayList` in play.

Answer (score 0):

```
player_data.add(new Player(R.drawable.blue, "Player " + nextPlayerNum, 0));
adapter.add(new Player(R.drawable.blue, "Player " + nextPlayerNum, 0));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

what this means??

you should never add items like this.

instead you can do like,

declare and initialize array list globally.

```
ArrayList<Player> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

then after everytime you should add data in array list and just call.

```
 list.add(PLAYER OBJECT);
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Answer (score 0):

comment below line and try once

```
 adapter.add(new Player(R.drawable.blue, "Player " + nextPlayerNum, 0));
```

It is not required as you are already adding data in list.

Comment: I went ahead and commented out adapter.add but I am still seeing the crash. I verified that the length of `player_data` and `adapter` are both 5 after calling `player_data.add(new Player(R.drawable.blue, "Player " + nextPlayerNum, 0));`, but once I call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` it crashes